# div display none breaks style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a textarea for comments and a button to show or hide it (toggle). If I want to hide it by default (display: none) when I click the button to show it, the style is broken but if it's not hidden (display: block) I can click without problems, the style will be fine.

html:

```
<a id="1" class="comment_button a_button" title="Dejar un comentario">Comentar</a>

<div id="hide_1" class="rows" style="display: none;">
    <ul id="UL_101">
        <!-- New comment row -->
        <li class="newComment_row">
            <div class="userComments_photo">
                <img class="photo" src="/images/profile/' . $_SESSION['photo'] .'" alt="" />
            </div>
            <textarea id="' . $imgID . '" class="textarea" rows="1" placeholder="Escribe un comentario..." title="Escribe un comentario..."></textarea>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
.rows {
    height: auto;
    width: 494px;
    background: rgb(246, 247, 248) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    margin: 8px -12px -12px;
}
#UL_101 {
    width: 494px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(225, 226, 227);
}
/* li */
 .newComment_row {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 470px;
    background: rgb(246, 247, 248) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0px 12px;
    padding: 4px 0px 8px 0px;
}
.textarea {
    resize: none;
    width: 416px;
    font: normal normal normal 12px/15.3599996566772px Helvetica, Arial, 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    position: initial;
    padding: 8px 3px 0 3px;
    margin: 0 7px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and jquery:

```
// show rows
$('.comment_button').on('click', function () {
    $('#hide_' + this.id).slideToggle('fast');
});

function h(e) {
    $(e).css({
        'height': 'auto',
        'overflow-y': 'hidden'
    }).height(e.scrollHeight);
}
$('textarea').each(function () {
    h(this);
}).on('input', function () {
    h(this);
});
```

display: none breaks the style: http://jsfiddle.net/cb41hmpo/
display: block does not break it: http://jsfiddle.net/cb41hmpo/1/

It seems the problem is the auto-height function... Is there a way to fix this?

I'd like to keep that textarea size if possible, whatever the changes are.

It's not a big deal but if display is set to block and I click the button, the textarea placeholder text appears some fuzzy or blurred for a second, is that a normal thing or can it be fixed?

Comment: Who have the decency to dislike my question could, at least, leave a comment explaining the motive of his/her dislike...

Answer (score 1):

If we go through your code

```
function h(e) {
  alert(e.scrollHeight);
  $(e).css({
    'height': 'auto',
    'overflow-y': 'hidden'
}).**height(e.scrollHeight)**;
}
```

If you look at the bold section here you are assigning the scrollHeight to $e. If we do an alert we can see that the height of textarea when the parent div is hidden is 0 and it is 23 when the div is shown it  is 23 px. Now in the (star marked -->height(e.scrollHeight) text we are assigning explicitly that height to the textarea (bold text). Hence, it is smaller in size. Hence  your *height auto* is not coming into picture as you are assigning height by e.scrollHeight.

Try removing the bold text from both the snippets. The result you will get will be the same.

Hope this be of some help.

Happy Learning :)

Comment: Right! I see. But what bold text do you mean?

Comment: sorry... the editor didnt make it bold :)
I was talking about 
    height(e.scrollHeight)

Comment: If I delete that, the textarea won't auto-height :( How can I specify in that function the initial height??

Comment: Oh.. But then we may have to look for some other way for this which may include how you structuring your html containers as assigning scollHeight to height() is same as assigning a fixed height to the container. Then height auto wont do much. Will try to look into this and get back to you

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to figure out where to change the initial textarea heigh, it's adding a high value (57px) and I need something smaller (32px). Do you have any idea where to change this?